# if $f(x,y,y')$ does not depend on $x$ then the Euler-Lagrange equation becomes in:

Tags: real-analysis, calculus-of-variations, euler-lagrange-equation

if $f(x,y,y')$ does not depend on $x$ then the Euler-Lagrange equation becomes in:

$$f(x,u,u')-u'f_{y'}(x,u,u')=c  $$ in $[x_0,x_1]$ for some $c \in \mathbb{R}$

Ok I need prove this, I know that if $u$ is a local minimum then

$$f_{y}(x,u,u')-\frac{d}{dx}(f_{y}(x,u,u'))=0 $$ in $[x_0,x_1]$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given $f(x,y,y')$ we have

$$
\frac{df}{dx}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}y'+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y'}y''\ \ \ \ \ \ (1)
$$

and also

$$
\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial y'}y'\right)=\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial y'}\right)y'+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y'}y''\ \ \ \ \ \ \ (2)
$$

and according the Euler-Lagrange equation we have

$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}-\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial y'}\right)=0\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (3)
$$

then using $(3)$ into $(2)$ we obtain

$$
\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial y'}y'\right)=\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}y'+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y'}y''\ \ \ \ \ \ \ (4)
$$

now from $(1),(4)$

$$
\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial y'}y'-f\right)=-\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}
$$

but $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = 0$ because $f=f(y,y')$ hence

$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial y'}y'-f = C
$$